# How to Export a Personal Geodatabase to ArcSDE

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, export, personal-geodatabase

I want to copy/export my personal geodatabase which consists of feature datasets, relationship class etc to an Enterprise geodatabase. What would be the best approach?

Comment: Yes I can copy feature classes or feature datasets but I am unable to copy Relationship classes. Also, I am trying to minimize manual copying and pasting as I have lot of data. Thanks for your suggestion!!!

Answer (score 3):

A simple copy and paste of PGDB feature classes or feature datasets to SDE geodatabase in ArcCatalog should work (if you have admin rights on SDE database).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what version of ArcGIS you're using, but the Distributed Geodatabase toolbar should be available.   This toolbar contains an Extract Data wizard, which should accomplish what you're trying to do.  Try following these steps from the Esri help:  [Copying a geodatabase using Extract Data Wizard in ArcMap](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000030000000)